# How to print paragraph field values in paragraph template?

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I'm trying to output paragraph field values in a sample paragraph template, but it does not work. I created a twig template in paragraph/paragraph--article--default.html.twig

I have a field called field_action and I tried:

```
{% block paragraph %}
    <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
      {% block content %}
        {{content.field_action}}
        {{content.field_action.value}}

      {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

Nothing happens.

If I write {{content}} everything is fine, but I would like to customize output.

Comment: Is the `block content` necessary? Otherwise this should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print out single fields I usually use, `{{ paragraph.field_action.value }}`. That should also work for you.

In the case of an entity reference field, you need to use `{{ paragraph.field_action.entity.field.value }}`.